# How to detect HTML5 constraint violation for input fields?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

HTML5 umbrella specs have the `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class for styling `input` with broken content.

My Firefox 38.2.1 doesn't send a form if one of the fields is invalid.

How can I -- in pure browser JS / DOM API -- get the field containing invalid data?

How can I do that check for the entire form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all invalid elements using `querySelectorAll`.

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function () {
    var invalid = document.querySelectorAll('input:invalid');
};
```

As you can see from the (simplistic) example above, I am doing this on the click event because the form won't submit if there are invalid elements.

The `invalid` variable contains a collection of invalid elements.

You can see a [working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe3wa1L7/).

Comment: Thanks! That really solution for my question. Some quick digging in DOM specs show me that there no direct functions/attributes on `Node` that answer the question but I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. See comment of  *Traktor53* and answer of *toskv*. Now there are two proper answer and each may be useful depending on additional requirements. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1):

The **HTMLFormElement** object/type has an **checkValidity** method you can use to check that.

Check it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement

Comment: Hm..., I follow links on http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR  and seems that DOM level 1/2/3/4 specs doesn't have `HTMLFormElement.checkValidity` Is that right that `checkValidity` an experimental feature?

Comment: @gavenkoa It's part of the HTML5 standard - see section [4.10.21.3 The constraint validation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api) for further information on `checkValidity` - and more

Comment: @Wolf, yes I meant the invalid event, I changed it to the method though, it makes more sense to use that. :)

Comment: @Traktor53 Wow! This is awesome! Your comment is really an answer to question!